# DevExtreme Datagrid with buttons?

Tags: c#, devexpress, .net-6.0, devextreme

I have a DevExtreme datagrid being produced from a list being generated in the OnGet method. I want to have a column in which it will change from active or inactive and each time they click one of these buttons they will need to make a post to the code behind.

```
 @(
            Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<SupplierPortal.Models.SecurityGroupListViewModel>()
            .ID("MenuItemGrid")
            .DataSource(Model.gridSecurityGroups)
            .AllowColumnResizing(true)
            .ColumnResizingMode(ColumnResizingMode.Widget)
            .Paging(p => p.PageSize(10))
            .Pager(p => p
            .ShowPageSizeSelector(true)
            .AllowedPageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200 })
            .Visible(true)
            .ShowInfo(true)
            )
            .HeaderFilter(h => h.Visible(true))
            .RowAlternationEnabled(false)
            .ShowBorders(true)
            .ShowRowLines(true)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.AddFor(r => r.DisplayParm)
                    .HeaderCellTemplate("Display")
                    .CellTemplate(
                        @<text>
                            @{
                            string DisplayGroupId = "<%- value %>";
                            }

                            <a href="../SecurityGroupMaintenance/SecurityGroupDisplay?handler=Display&GroupId=@Html.Raw(DisplayGroupId)"><i class="bi bi-display"></i></a>

                        </text>
                    )
                    .Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.GroupID);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.InternalExternal);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.Description);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.DefaultMenu);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.ActiveInactive);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.EditParm)
                    .HeaderCellTemplate("Edit")
                    .Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    .CellTemplate(
                        @<text>
                            @{
                                string EditGroupId = "<%- value %>";
                            }
                        <a href="../SecurityGroupMaintenance/SecurityGroupEdit?handler=Edit&GroupId=@Html.Raw(EditGroupId)"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>

                        </text>);
                columns.AddFor(r => r.ActivateGroupId)
                    .HeaderCellTemplate("Activate/Inactivate")
                    .CellTemplate(
                        @<text>
                                @{
                                        string ActivateGroupIdParm = "<%- value %>";
                                        string ActiveCode = ActivateGroupIdParm.Substring(0, 1);              
                                        string ActivateGroupId = ActivateGroupIdParm.Substring(1);
                                    }
                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="GroupId" value="@Html.Raw(ActivateGroupIdParm.Substring(1))"/>
                                <input type="hidden" value="@Html.Raw(ActivateGroupIdParm.Substring(0, 1))"/>
                                        @if(ActiveCode == "1")
                                        {
                                            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Activate">
                                                <i class="bi bi-toggle-on activeBtn"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        } else
                                        {
                                            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Activate">
                                                <i class="bi bi-toggle-off inactiveBtn"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        }
                            </form>
                        </text>);
            })
            )
```

However the hidden fields in the form located in the cell template method off the last column do not return the actual value rather than the string that generates the parameter which can be used in redirects in anchor tags as you can see in other columns.

In the developer tools this is how the values are generated [image]